# Wowza Streaming Live Server Data two questions

Tags: wowza

Does Wowza Streaming Server (used as live streaming services) care about the direction of data stream?

1. Possibility of Wowza Server as a server side mode and client side mode
2. Since I am trying to send data stream via LTE, the cost of sending data stream is very high. So I am wondering if it is possible to have live stream data only when the request is present.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what do you mean by "Wowza acting as a client" to me. Wowza can be configured to be an edge instance, that pulls stream from an origin Wowza server, when you want to have multiple, possibly geographically distributed stream sources.

Or, if you think about the other case, Wowza accepts the stream from encoders, in which case the data flow direction is also towards Wowza. This is the case when you install for example a Flash Media Live Encoder, or a VLC and push your encoded stream "into" Wowza, which then distributes this stream to all other players.

But obviously Wowza won't act as a video player to you.. :-)

Can you clarify your first question, maybe I can give a better answer then.